# Highlight menu item when on a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently using this code to display a menu of pages. I'm using CSS to target the class `current_page_item` which works fine until you're on a page with a custom post type.

How can I target that class when the page the user is on is a custom post-type such as news or events?

```
<div id="menu-repeat">
<?php $args = array(
'depth'        => 1,
'show_date'    => '',
'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
'child_of'     => 0,
'exclude'      => '1908, 6282, 6380',
'include'      => '',
'title_li'     => __(''),
'echo'         => 1,
'authors'      => '',
'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
'link_before'  => '',
'link_after'   => '',
'walker' => '' ); ?>
<ul><div class="menu-button"><?php wp_list_pages( $args, 'sort_column=menu_order' ); ?></div></ul>
```

Comment: How did you add the custom post type item to the menu?

Comment: @mrweb I've got a page called Events that I want to be highlighted when I'm on a custom post type called events.

Comment: To further clarify, you want the menu item to be highlighted on 1) **all** "Event" post type posts, 2) a single post named "Events," or 3) The "Event" post type archive? The code you list only displays Pages anyway, not custom post types.

Comment: @mrwweb I want it to be highlighted on ALL event post types and the event post type archive. Bear in mind the menu is also made up of just normal pages (hence the code above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for a one-off site, I would suggest doing this with CSS. Philosophically, adding the `current_page_item` class to a menu item when that's not true feels a bit wrong too.

As long as you're using the `body_class()` function on your `<body>` element in the theme, there should be a class called `single-{event}` where "{event}" is the id of the post type. Hence, add the selector `.single-{event} .page-item-{ID}` where "{ID}" is the page ID of the events page (you'll see that as the class on the menu item as well).

Comment: Awesome, been struggling with that one across several sites. Thanks very much! Also opened my eyes to the <body class> tag!!

Comment: Glad to help. Check out it's awesome sister [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) and make sure to note that you can pass additional classes to both functions as arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this has been reported as a bug. The only solutions I've seen is on the trac ticket [#17590](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17590)

```
function my_page_css_class( $css_class, $page ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->ID == $page->ID ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
    }
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'my_page_css_class', 10, 2 );
```

The alternative would be using some javascript magic to insert a class using `addClass`

Comment: I want to highlight a page called Events when on a custom post type called events.